Visual Studio 2022 Windows Forms Designer Hierarchy
I'm trying to find some clear option in Visual Studio 2022 to display the hierarchy of individual placed controls and containers, for easier manipulation between containers and placed elements. I find it very confusing to move control elements from one container to another directly in the preview of the window itself and not in some clear list, where the parent-child relationships between elements and containers are clearly visible. If you are familiar with the Scene Builder in Java FX, for example, this hierarchy is clearly displayed here. Java FX Scene Builder Hierarchy of placed objects
Reason why i am looking for such feature is when some components are obstructed by containers and i want to move them, into other container, without the need of moving everything above, and when i properly set positions to some control elements, moving them will change their positions and I will have to change them again in the properties.
If there is no such option to display the hierarchy in Visual Studio Windows forms designer, are there any alternatives? Any external tools that can work with windows forms better and more clearly? I'm working with C# and .NET framework.
I tried to find the answer on the web in text form or in the form of a youtube video, but nothing met my expectations. Video guides are always so simple and they always place containers first and just move the elements into them, but what if you change your mind in the middle of the process? You need to plan it perfectly from the beginning, because every change comes with a lot of tweaking? I know its more like a quality of life issue, but it feels so frustrating to design without this feature.

View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline  (CTRL+ALT+T)

Try to use Document Outline in Visual Studio, which allows you easily change the hierarchy of your controls:
View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline
